# Are there out-of-universe reasons that Daenerys doesn't invade Westeros immediately?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Naturally, only Martin, Benioff and Weiss know the broad character arcs for ASOIAF. Why did GRRM choose to (spoilers ASOS)

> keep Daenerys in Meereen by installing her rule there, rather than taking her ships and sailing to Westeros? The in-universe explanation seems sound enough, that Dany needs practice in learning to rule a city, but I'm not quite sure why GRRM wanted Dany to wait so long before even touching the shores of Westeros.

I'm looking for cogent, reasonable theories, or if you have quotes from GRRM that explain this, that would be even better.

Comment: This question is offtopic since there is no "correct answer" and is primarily opinion based

Comment: @CyanAngel: not necessarily. Martin might have discussed the issue and shed some light on it.

Comment: Anything stated by Martin would not constitute really a "theory" in the context of this question would it?

Comment: No, then it would be a definitive answer, @CyanAngel.

Comment: So your not asking for theories your asking for statements made by Martin?

Comment: I'm asking for cogent explanations or theories. If someone has a quote from GRRM that explains Dany in Meereen, even better.

Comment: Dany in Meeren and J. Targaryen on the Iron Throne = Targaryens rule the known world *puts his crystall ball aside*
Tbh:I do not think Martin would spoil such an important part of his story,because it would throw Dany completly out of the race for the IT.

Comment: @LeoKing Fair enough, if you make an edit to the question to clarify that, the system will then let me retract my downvote

Comment: Okey-doke. Any better?

Comment: Asking for theories from GRRM: OK; that's definitive. Asking for theories from anyone: too broad/primarily opinion based.

Comment: You guys are going crazy with close votes. This cannot be the purpose of having this close reason, to just close any question that might have something to do with opinions. Some questions about literature contain analysis, and you will just have to learn to live with that amount of uncertainty. If you get "bad" answers to a question like this, use the downvote, its what it is there for.

Comment: Some of the things involved in this answer is that GRRM initially planned for a 5 year gap, where events, humans and beasts alike could mature and develop, but he then decided to skip the gap, which gave him the problem which he named "The Mereneese Knot", and no doubt is one of the reasons the books have been so delayed.

Comment: The out-of-universe answer is probably the same as the in-universe answer.

Comment: She is a character that often diametrically opposes Jon Snow (aka "a song of ICE (cold north) and FIRE (hot east). Both her and Jon have to learn some things to grow into their destined roles. Having them grow apart & meet at the end of the story & somewhere in the middle, is thematic, while also world-building. Dany is also only 13 in books when she is wedded to Drogo. There are so many other characters stories he had to develop, needed some time to do that and change the landscape of Westoros before she arrives. It's possible that book characters introduced late, still play some major role.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In fact, there is. George R.R. Martin has very specifically answered this question.

In [this](http://observationdeck.io9.com/george-r-r-martin-the-complete-unedited-interview-886117845) interview with Charlie Jane Anders, GRRM says:

> I get complaints sometimes that nothing happens(in AFFC) — but they're
> defining "nothing," I think, differently than I am. I don't think it
> all has to battles and sword fights and assassinations. Character
> development and [people] changing is good, and there are some tough
> things in there that I think a lot of writers skip over. I'm glad I
> didn't skip over these things.

Coming the point of this question, he says:

> And that has been interesting, you know. Jon Snow as Lord Commander.
> Dany as Queen, struggling with rule. So many books don't do that.
> There is a sense when you're writing something in high fantasy, you're
> in a dialogue with all the other high fantasy writers that have
> written. And there is always this presumption that if you are a good
> man, you will be a good king. [Like] Tolkien — in Return of the King,
> Aragorn comes back and becomes king, and then [we read that] "he ruled
> wisely for three hundred years." Okay, fine. It is easy to write that
> sentence, “He ruled wisely”.
>
> What does that mean, he ruled wisely? What were his tax policies? What
> did he do when two lords were making war on each other? Or barbarians
> were coming in from the North? What was his immigration policy? What
> about equal rights for Orcs? I mean did he just pursue a genocidal
> policy, "Let’s kill all these fucking Orcs who are still left over"?
> Or did he try to redeem them? You never actually see the nitty-gritty
> of ruling.
>
> I guess there is an element of fantasy readers that don't want to see
> that. I find that fascinating. Seeing someone like Dany actually
> trying to deal with the vestments of being a queen and getting
> factions and guilds and [managing the] economy. They burnt all the
> fields [in Meereen]. They've got nothing to import any more. They're
> not getting any money. I find this stuff interesting.

And in [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rollingstone.com%2Ftv%2Fnews%2Fgeorge-r-r-martin-the-rolling-stone-interview-20140423&ei=5I7sU8CwKcu48gW3lYLQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFQpVd1UvB-yX-kGBypYbBSr54x0w&bvm=bv.73231344,d.dGc) Rolling Stones interview, he sums it up with:

> In real life, real-life kings had real-life problems to deal with.
> Just being a good guy was not the answer. You had to make hard, hard
> decisions. Sometimes what seemed to be a good decision turned around
> and bit you in the ass; it was the law of unintended consequences.
> I've tried to get at some of these in my books. My people who are
> trying to rule don't have an easy time of it. Just having good
> intentions  doesn't make you a wise king.

**TL;DR;** A good human being doesn't translate into a good king. Dany is good, just, ambitious, wants to end slavery & give freedom to the oppressed. She does that, but what happens after that? What happens to the oppressed and enslaved after they gain freedom? How does she rule a kingdom when she wins it?

If all GRRM wanted to write was an epic war novel, he would have written about the Mad King's reign, & how Ned & Robert thwarted his unjust rule.

Comment: Great answer, good quotes too.

Comment: Great answer. Many people have made comparisons to the leadership abilities of Cersei in aFfC and Dany and Jon in aDwD. Specifically, the lack thereof.

Comment: Excellent conclusion